# Replacing a single character when there are duplicates

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, for-loop

All I'm trying to make is a program that loops through a word or phrase character-by-character like this:

```
word: "dog"
d
do
dog
do
d
```

I wrote this:

```
word = 'factory'
temp_word = ''
temp_word2 = ''

# Builds up 'factory' letter-by-letter into temp_word
for i in word:
    temp_word += i
    print(temp_word)

# Takes letters off 1 by 1
for i in reversed(word):
    temp_word2 = temp_word.replace(i, "")
    temp_word = temp_word2
    print(temp_word2)
```

and the output is exactly what I want:

```
f
fa
fac
fact
facto
factor
factory
factor
facto
fact
fac
fa
f
```

But, if there is a repeated letter, it'll remove both at once, like this:

```
h
he
hel
hell
hello
hell
he
he
h
```

How can I make it just remove the one letter, without removing both? Can't think of a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you *have* to use a tempvariable, or are you allowed to just use string slicing?

```
for i in range(1,len(word)+1):
    print(word[:i])

for i in range(len(word)-1,0,-1): #the third argument of range is step, and -1 causes range to step backwards
    print(word[:i])
```

Comment: slicing creates a new string

Comment: ...derp. I somehow managed to read this as a python2.7 question. Fixing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well, yes, but this way you don't have to deal with tempvariables or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass count as `1` to replace to only replace one occurrence.

```
temp_word2 = temp_word.replace(i, "",1)
```

You could also just slice the last letter off:

```
for i in reversed(word):
    temp_word2 = temp_word[:-1]
```

Comment: Out of those 2 options, which do you think would be the preferred method?

Comment: They both create a new string so probably not much difference

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, it's not the best. Depending of what you want to do with this, I can provide a more specific solution

```
word = 'hello'
temp_word = ''
temp_word2 = ''

for k in word:
    temp_word += k
    print temp_word
while temp_word:
    temp_word = temp_word[:-1]
    print temp_word
```

**EDIT**

I prefer this version more

```
word = 'hello'
for k in list(range(1,len(word)+1)) + list(range(len(word)-1,1,-1)):
    print word[:k]
```